# Error while initializing classpath container : Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am trying to gradle build a project in eclipse. Then I got the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Artifact 'junit:junit:4.8.2@jar' not found.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:27)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:118)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:466)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:442)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:437)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DelegatingBuildModelAction.run(DelegatingBuildModelAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:98)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Artifact 'junit:junit:4.8.2@jar' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolve(ExternalResourceResolver.java:494)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.resolve(ExternalResourceResolverAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$2.run(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.resolve(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LocalModuleVersionRepository.resolve(LocalModuleVersionRepository.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.IvyContextualiser$1.invoke(IvyContextualiser.java:44)
    at $Proxy21.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain$ModuleVersionRepositoryArtifactResolverAdapter.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:164)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ResolvedArtifactFactory$1.create(ResolvedArtifactFactory.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.getFilesStrict(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFiles(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
    ... 59 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.613 secs
```

But i have junit 4.8.2 jar in gradle and maven repositories and i also add it in project's build classpath. Now whenever I open eclipse I got the following error before building also.

```
Error while initializing classpath container
Artifact 'junit:junit:4.8.2@jar' not found.
Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.4-bin.zip'.
```

**build.gradle**

```
./*
 * Copyright 2012 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/maven.gradle"

dependencies {
    compile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    compile "log4j:log4j:$log4jVersion"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonCoreVersion"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonDatabindVersion"
    compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:$hazelcastVersion"
    compile "io.netty:netty-all:$nettyVersion"
}

artifacts {
    platform jar
}


test {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

  systemProperty 'vertx.test.timeout', 60

  jvmArgs '-server', '-Xms128m', '-Xmx1024m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m', '-XX:NewRatio=2'

  testLogging { exceptionFormat "full" }
}
```

Comment: We need more information: 1. The *exact* actions you took/commands you issued 2. The relevant parts of your build script. Apparently you have a `buildscript` block that declares JUnit as a direct or transitive dependency? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I didnt give any commands just copy project from my friend and try to build.

Comment: By "The exact actions you took/commands you issued" I mean what *exactly* you did to get the error, what *exactly* you mean by "add it in project's build classpath", etc. Also we would need to see `$rootDir/gradle/maven.gradle`.

Comment: i just import project in eclipse and build it. I dint do anything more.

Answer (score 1):

Your local repo maybe corrupted.
Try to uninstall junit from your local repo and redownload it.

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/junit
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided, my best guess is that the problem is related to a `buildscript` section in either `maven.gradle` or another build script. For example, you might be missing a repository declaration there. To rule out that the problem is related to Eclipse (integration), I'd first try to build the project on the command line (e.g. `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies`).